# Android Maps api release key not working

Tags: android

I looked over all the stackoverflow questions related to this, but nothing worked. Sorry if this is asked already.

I have the Google maps api integrated into my app, and everything works fine in development. I got a debug api key based on the debug.keystore file and it works just fine.

Then I went ahead and got a release api key based on the keystore file that I use to sign the app. However, all I see are grey tiles - the maps don't show up. I have the **uses-library** tag inside of my **application tag** in the manifest. I have the permission for the internet in the manifest, as well as **android:debuggable="false"** (though this doesn't seem to change anything).

What else could I be missing?

Comment: Did you clean/rebuild after putting in the api key for your release keystore?

Comment: I have an automated build setup, which always does a clean build.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Are you running it in Eclipse or other IDE?

Comment: You have created map key with debug.keystore and while releasing the apk you signed it with the actual/different keystore. am i right?

Comment: I use Eclipse.
Correct. I have a different keystore file for release - I used the debug.keystore file for development.
I think the issue might be with my automated build - it might be using a different release keystore file. I will check that.

Comment: My hunch was right! The automated build was using a different keystore than the one I was using in Eclipse. Hence the issue. Thanks everyone for your help. My issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

**How I've solved it:**

It is important to make a new(!) API key for your release-keystore because the old API key generated for debug keystore will not work with release keystore. Here it is the procedure how to do it: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint

In few words:

1. make a fingerprint (MD5) for your keystore, e.g. by this batch file:

   @echo off 
   "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool.exe" -v -list -keystore my-release-key.keystore > my-release-md5-fingerprint.txt

   echo your google api key (md5) saved to the file my-release-md5-fingerprint.txt

   pause
2. Go to the google site where APi is generated: 
   http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

And copy-paste to the appropriate field your MD5 fingerprint which looks like the following 
94:1E:43:49:87:73:BB:E6:A6:88:D7:20:F1:8E:B5:98
(no extra spaces or additional symbols allowed).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Release key from another link. Debug key and Release key are different. See here for "how to create debug key and release key differently": http://chocotech.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-debug-key-and-release-key-for.html

Answer (score -1):

In your MapView you have to specify your ApiKey :

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:apiKey="@string/mapKey"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

where mapKey is you ApiKey (here I define it in my Strings).

Comment: Yes I already have that. As I mentioned it works fine in development. it is only when I switch it to the release api key that I run into issues.

Comment: If he has it working while debugging, he has already done this correctly.